# Unable to retrieve column values from one of the tables joined in a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql

I have stored procedures(it work fine in sql) which can return data from two tables as below:

stored procedures:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.spp_adm_user_user_group_sel

AS 
BEGIN 

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 SELECT g.name as Group_Name, u.fullname, u.designation, u.email, u.mobile 
 FROM TBL_ADM_USER_GROUP g, TBL_ADM_USER u
 WHERE 
    g.id = u.group_id AND (g.deleted IS NULL OR g.deleted <> 1)

 END
```

and this code to access stored procedures.

```
 public List<GroupUserList> GetData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<GroupUserList> details = new List<GroupUserList>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.Config.ConnStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spp_adm_user_user_group_sel", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                GroupUserList usr = new GroupUserList();


                usr.fullname = dr["fullname"].ToString();
                usr.email = dr["email"].ToString();
                usr.name = dr["name"].ToString();
                details.Add(usr);
            }


            return details;
        }

    }
```

I am wondering here why data can return from TBL_ADM_USER and can not be returned from TBL_ADM_USER_GROUP !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update your code

```
public List<GroupUserList> GetData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<GroupUserList> details = new List<GroupUserList>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.Config.ConnStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spp_adm_user_user_group_sel", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                GroupUserList usr = new GroupUserList();

                usr.name = dr["Group_Name"].ToString();
                usr.fullname = dr["fullname"].ToString();
                usr.designation = dr["designation"].ToString();
                usr.mobile = dr["mobile"].ToString();
                usr.email = dr["email"].ToString();

                details.Add(usr);
            }


            return details;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
usr.name = dr["name"].ToString();
```

to

```
usr.name = dr["Group_Name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please add relevant as well explaining why the suggested code snippet will work see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you execute only the sql query? Does it return the expected values? As far as I can see you should write a join between the two tables for retrieving the correct result.

Comment: Wouldn't be better as a comment? Get 50 reputation and comment anywhere you want.